# Sitecore Item/Subitem sorting with Linq

Tags: linq, sorting, sitecore

How would one go about sorting a list of Sitecore subitems using Linq with the following method, AND converting/casting the "sortedlist" back to `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item[]`:

```
...
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item[] subitems = current.SelectItems(query);
var sortedList = (from entry in subitems orderby entry.Fields["Title"].Value ascending select entry);  
...
```

Note: I have unsuccessfully attempted to sort it in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the .Field from the items. Just use the value directly using **["Title"]**, e.g.:

```
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item[] subitems = current.SelectItems(query);
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item[] sorted = subitems.OrderBy(i => i["Title"]).ToArray();
```

Comment: Agreed, much safer to access a field value this way.

Comment: No chance to get a null reference exception for the Field that can be null.